# How to modify a database through SQL injection UNION?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

I need help with an sqli exercise. I used sqlmap to find a UNION  vulnerability.

I managed to get the H2 version with this payload:

```
string') UNION ALL SELECT NULL,H2VERSION(),NULL,NULL,NULL--
```

But I would like to modify the database. I tried with this payload:

```
string') UNION ALL SELECT NULL,UPDATE ITEMS SET NAME = 'Hello' WHERE ID = 2,NULL,NULL,NULL--
```

But it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: "But it did not work." -- that doesn't tell us anything. What actually happened?

Comment: The payload does not look syntactically correct. A stacked statement would likely involve a semi-colon but you cannot mix a select with an update query.